# How to measure open-drain vs. hi-z with multimeter

Tags: multimeter, gpio, open-drain, high-impedance

I have an output pin configured to be either open-drain or hi-z. How can I use my multimeter to tell which mode it is in?

Comment: Can you make sure the output value is low while you do the test?

Comment: Also, what device are you using? Is it a microcontroller or an FPGA or something else? A link to the datasheet of the device would give us the most information to help answer your question.

Comment: I am using an STM32F103 microcontroller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pin can only be high impedance or open collector then you can add a pullup resistor to the pin and try to write a logic `0` to it, If the pin voltage goes low it is open-collector, if it stays at a high voltage then it is high impedance.